# How is low bandwidth data like text sent to the GPU

Tags: graphics, gpu, shared-memory

I've been really struggling to find an answer to this question and thought it would be pretty easy to find online but alas no. I can appreciate that this question might be hardware dependent but i can see that high bandwidth data like shaders, textures etc are sent to the GPU via DMA by the graphics API setting the command buffer in host memory and the GPU later reading this out but what happens with low bandwidth data like when typing in a Word prossessor or this field on stackoverflow right now. How does the text data get to the GPU? Does it go like following?

MS Word > Graphics API > Kernel Mode driver > sends the glyphs (bitmaps) to MMIO register on GPU which then feeds into Framebuffer on the graphics card? As i know the host can't write the framebuffer directly? Or have i got this completely wrong and all modern data transfer to the GPU is done via DMA?

Thank you

Comment: Please someone help me answer this? It's driving my inner nerd insane lol

Comment: Have i asked this on wrong forum?